# How to make RDLC report two column

Tags: report, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a simple report which is supposed to be used for printing stickers. The sticker paper is A4 size and it has two columns. I successfully managed to print data to left column. I also want to print data to right column too. My current report looks like this :

```html
[Title]
[NameLastName]
[Address]
```

How can I make my report to fill data to two columns? Thanks.

EDIT :

I have generated another column as suggested in other questions. But the result is still one column, Can anyone tell me the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it [I think] is to:

- add additional "columnNumber" column and make it "1" for, say, all odd rows and "2" for all even rows.
- then place two tables side by side and make the same DataSetName property for both of them
- then filter the data in each table based on the columnNumber Value (add Filter to Filters property of the table)