# Asp.Net RDLC how can I split rows into columns

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, row-number

I've added a simple table control (tablix) to a report view, in there I've put a data field  from a dataset... but, this field is filled with a very large list of items and I'd would like  keep all the rows in the same page, in different columns... this is what I got...

```
Column1

 Data1 
 Data2
 Data3
 Data4
 ...
 DataN
```

and this is what I want....

```
Column1      Column2    Column3
Data1         Data4      DataN
Data2         Data5
Data3         Data6
```

So in this way I'll could keep all the records in the same page...

Please Help! And thank you very much for reading...

Kind Regards,

Comment: You can try something similar to the solution to this recently asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126038/how-to-make-rdlc-report-two-column

Comment: Thank you very much #InitK, it's a very nice way to do that! I'll try it...